# Why isn't showing the panel I want?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

If I directly add the panel in the constructor it works fine but with the controller it does not.
When I clic on the menu one of the options "Reservas" or "Contabilidad" I want to change the panel shown and see other stuff.

This is my view

```
public class Vista extends JFrame{
private JMenuBar barraMenu=new JMenuBar();
private JMenu menu=new JMenu("Opciones");
private JMenuItem reservas=new JMenuItem("Reservas");
private JMenuItem contabilidad=new JMenuItem("Contabilidad");
private JMenuItem salir=new JMenuItem("Salir");
private Controlador controlador;
private Reservas panelReservas=new Reservas();
private Contabilidad panelContabilidad=new Contabilidad();

public Vista(Controlador controlador){
    super("Reservas Hotel");
    this.controlador=controlador;
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setSize(600,500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setJMenuBar(barraMenu);
    this.crearMenu();
    this.anadirEscuchadores();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

private void crearMenu() {
    menu.add(reservas);
    menu.add(contabilidad);
    menu.add(salir);
    barraMenu.add(menu);
}

private void anadirEscuchadores() {
    reservas.addActionListener(controlador);
    contabilidad.addActionListener(controlador);
    salir.addActionListener(controlador);
}

public void cambiarAReservas() {
    this.remove(panelContabilidad);
    this.add(panelReservas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void cambiarAContabilidad() {
    this.remove(panelReservas);
    this.add(panelContabilidad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

}

This is my controller

```
public class Controlador implements ActionListener{
private Vista vista;
private GestorBD modelo;

public Controlador(){
    vista=new Vista(this);
    modelo=new GestorBD();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
    switch(evento.getActionCommand()){
        case "Reservas":
            vista.cambiarAReservas();
            break;
        case "Contabilidad":
            vista.cambiarAContabilidad();
            break;
        case "Salir":
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

The panel objects just have a jlabel with a hello written to test

Comment: Use a CardLayout. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Comment: That works too, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself. The .pack() was missing.
But I have the doubt, why isnt working with repaint but it does with pack?

```
public void cambiarAReservas() {
    this.remove(panelContabilidad);
    this.add(panelReservas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.pack();
}

public void cambiarAContabilidad() {
    this.remove(panelReservas);
    this.add(panelContabilidad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.pack();
}
```

Comment: Swing layout is lazy, in order to update the ui dynamically, you need to tell Swing when you want the layout to be updated. You do this by calling `revalidate` followed by `repaint` on the container you've updated in order to trigger a layout and paint pass. `pack` is basically doing this for you, but it is generally less efficient and make have undesirable side affects